# Is the <blockquote> tag working correctly on Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: support, formatting

I've been trying to use the `<blockquote>` tag to include literal output in this forum, but I cannot get it to work for me. My understanding is that if a chunk of text is surrounded by the `<blockquote>` and `</blockquote>` tags, then newlines within that chunk will  be preserved. But that doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: Only a small portion of HTML is supported, I would suggest you use markdown instead of HTML for formatting your post

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting for details on the markdown specification supported by thee sites.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need HTML. Instead, to make a blockquote, use the `>` character. Remember to have a blank line after the end of the blockquote. Here's an example:

```
> Ask Ubuntu is amazing!
```

Here's how that will render

> Ask Ubuntu is amazing!

And using multiple lines:

```
> Ask Ubuntu is amazing!
>
> Unix SE is very good, too!
```

And here is how that will render

> Ask Ubuntu is amazing!
>
> Unix SE is very good, too!

If you *really* want to use HTML instead of Markdown, you can. Here's how:

```
<blockquote>
Ask Ubuntu is amazing!
Unix SE is great, too!
</blockquote>
```

Remember to have a blank line after `</blockquote>` or strange things can happen.

And that will render as this:

> Ask Ubuntu is amazing!
> Unix SE is great, too!

You mentioned it isn't making a newline. You have to have an entire blank line if you want a linebreak, like this:

```
<blockquote>
Ask Ubuntu is amazing!

Unix SE is great, too!
</blockquote>
```

And that will render as this (with the newline as desired). For the Markdown version, just include a `>` on a line by itself to indicate a line break.

> Ask Ubuntu is amazing!
>
> Unix SE is great, too!

For the rest of the valid HTML tags on SE, see [this Meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/1081494)

---

However, for command output (or code), don't use blockquotes. Instead, use a codeblock, and you start end end those with three backticks (```` ``` ````).
Here's an example (you can optionally include a language, like C or Python, after the three backticks if you want, for syntax highlighting)

````
```c
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```
````

That will render like this:

```
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

If you're wondering why you have to include an entire blank line (or, in the Markdown version, add a `>` on a line by itself), check out [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7167519/16886597) that includes the reasons.

Comment: Now that I've rediscovered ```, I have no need for anything else.

Comment: `<pre>` and  `</pre>` is more visual IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Blockquote formatting does not preserve line breaks, which is why it should not be used to format output from a command - long output becomes horribly unreadable, and since blockquoted text, unlike unformatted text, also loses the *original line breaks* from the markdown text, it is impossible to fix the problem by editing!

Use code formatting to preserve line breaks in output from a terminal or code, or if the text is actually a quote rather than code(like text) and for some reason you really need to preserve the line breaks, you can insert line breaks as needed by putting two spaces and then a newline, though I rarely find any need to do so.